# Lattice on $(M(X,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{R}),\leq)$

Tags: measure-theory, lattice-orders

Show that $(M(X,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{R}),\leq)$ defines a lattice.

I know that $M(X,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{R})$ with the relation $\leq$ defines a partial order. Now, a lattice consists of a partially ordered set in which every two elements have a unique supremun and infimum.

But I really have no idea on how to proceed. I have read about Hasse diagrams but I don't think I can apply that here.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Consider two signed measures $\mu,\nu \in M(X,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{R})$ along with the Hahn decomposition $X = X^+\cup X^-$ corresponding to $\mu-\nu$.

Then show that $$(\mu\vee\nu)(A) = \mu(A\cap X^+)+\nu(A\cap X^-) \\ (\mu\wedge\nu)(A) = \mu(A\cap X^-) + \nu(A \cap X^+)$$  That is, show that these define signed measures in $M(X,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{R})$, that $\mu\wedge \nu \leq \mu,\nu \leq \mu\vee\nu$ and that any signed measure $\leq \mu,\nu$ is also $\leq \mu\wedge\nu$ (resp. for $\vee$)

Comment: Could you elaborate little bit more? I know what a Hahn decomposition is, but the other part you said I don't really understand.